# 2d interpolation table (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a table( w, alfa, eta ):

```
w = [0, 0.5, 1]
alfa = [0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9]
eta(0,0.3) = 0.23
eta(0.5,0) = 0.18
eta(0.5,0.6) = 0.65
eta(1,0.9) = 0.47
```

where, eta = f(w,alfa)

How can I interpolate the data to obtain all values ​​in this table?

I try griddata, interp2 etc but i can't do it.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding "I can't do it"? Please provide **short** code samples illustarting what you have tried and the resulting errors so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `griddata` should do the work in your case. However, you should notice that your inputs requires **extrapolation** as well as interpolation.

```
 >> [xout yout] = meshgrid( w, alfa ); % output points
 >> w_in = [ 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1 ];
 >> a_in = [ 0.3, 0, 0.6, 0.9 ];
 >> e_in = [ 0.23, 0.18, 0.65, 0.47 ];
 >> eta_out = griddata( w_in, a_in, e_in, xout, yout, 'linear' )
```